# How do I install Bower packages with Yarn?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, yarnpkg

From the project's [README](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/ab42cab05ddb49391a49893bb19e1d99e1fd2466/README.md#features):

> Multiple Registries: Install any package from either npm or Bower and keep your package workflow the same.

I'm assuming that means that I can install my Bower packages (listed in my project's `bower.json`) with Yarn. If this is the case, how would I go about doing that?

I'm not seeing any mention of Bower or using separate registries in the [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/). However, I do see the Bower registry listed in the [source](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/tree/master/src/registries).

Comment: Found this possibly related [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/898).

Comment: Another related [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/864).

Comment: Similar question in another [issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/617).

Answer (score 10):

UPDATE 11/4/16: Yarn decided to remove support for Bower. See the [Github pull request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/1441) and  [Bower's blog](https://bower.io/blog/2016/using-bower-with-yarn/). =(

ORIGINAL:
Bower just posted a [blog post](https://bower.io/blog/2016/using-bower-with-yarn/) about this topic. They seem excited about it, but point out that there are currently unresolved issues:

> Important note: As it stands right now there still seem to be some issues regarding Bower support. We are however confident that with the help of the community, these issues will be solved quickly as Yarn steps towards 1.0 in upcoming months.

He also refers to a [pull request](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/896) for a bower patch.

When I ran yarn, it deleted my `bower_components` folder (GitHub ticket here)! I really like yarn though, can't wait for the bower bugs to get resolved.

Comment: Just had the same experience. Ran yarn on an existing project. node_modules got changed/updated but bower_components got cleared out yarn v0.16.0

Comment: They just mentioned that they dropped Bower support

Answer (score 4):

If you add the following to package.json, bower install will be called and it works. It is a workaround though:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install"
}
```

Comment: Working for me.  Just to note, if you already have a postinstall script, you can append instructions with &&. Example "postinstall": " someting install && something remove && bower install && other commands"

Answer (score 3):

[Apparently](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/617#issuecomment-252962721), it **should** just work. Unfortunately, there's currently a [bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/617#issuecomment-252964394) where, if you have both a `package.json` and `bower.json` in the same project, only the npm packages are installed and the bower packages are ignored.

Normally, one would simply `yarn` or `yarn install` and both npm and bower dependencies would be installed.